# Javascript Regex partial matching

Tags: javascript, regex, string, matching, partial

I'm looking for a simple javascript regex that should match strings like

```
AAAA(abcd,6) 
AAAA(WXYZ,2)
```

but should not match strings like

```
AAAA(abcd,6,9)
```

I've come up withe the regex

```
AAAA\(.*,\d\)
```

but it matches all three of above.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `/AAAA\(\w{4},\d\)/`

Answer (score 2):

That's because `.*` will match anything including `,6`
Replace `.` with `[^,]` (any char but comma)

`AAAA\([^,]*,\d\)`

Comment: jslint complains about negative classes because they match so much. its usually faster and more reliable to be more specific if possible.

Comment: And that would find any character but `,`. If there are only letters to be matched than it is better to go with `\w+` or `\w{4}` for exactly 4 letters.

Comment: but we don't know what the possible characters are. Author can be more specific

Comment: @Adassko yes, you're right. It is hard to guess what the author exactly means and we can't read thoughts :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you want to match you could use something like

```
A{4}\([a-zA-Z]{4},\d\)
```

- A{4} matches the character A exactly 4 times.
- \( matches the character (
- [a-zA-Z]{4} matches any lower or upper case character from a to z
  exactly 4 times.
- , matches the character ,
- \d matches a digit.
- \) matches the character )

You could of course modify it to suit your needs, I recommend testing for instance at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gI1bK0/1) since it gives you instant feedback when you enter a regular expression.

Comment: I don't think there's any pros of replacing `AAAA` with `A{4}` - it's much less readable for me. I would leave `AAAA` as it is

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = /AAAA\([a-z]*,\d\)/i;

regex.test("AAAA(abcd,6)") => true;

regex.test("AAAA(WXYZ,2)") => true;

regex.test("AAAA(abcd,6,9)") => false;
```